# Setting EnterCriticalSection timeout

Tags: winapi, concurrency, locking, critical-section

Is there a way to set a timeout on `EnterCriticalSection()`? There is `TryEnterCriticalSection()`, but that would require me to spin, or use `Sleep()`.

Comment: That's the only way. If you want a better timer you'll have to use a heavier synchronisation object like a mutex.

Comment: That is not *entirely* true. The `EnterCriticalSection()` documentation says: ""*This function can raise EXCEPTION_POSSIBLE_DEADLOCK if a wait operation on the critical section times out. **The timeout interval is specified by the following registry value: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\CriticalSectionTimeout`**.*" A CriticalSection does contain a waitable object, so you could theoretically wait on that directly with a timeout (I wouldn't suggest it, though). The object is normally created on-demand during contention, but you can create it beforehand...

Comment: ... That said, if you need to use a waitable lock with timeout, it is best to use one that actually supports it, such as a mutex or event.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do timed wait with critical section. Its timeout is pretty large by default, and it is a debugging facility, not intended for normal usage.

As @Remy Lebeau mentioned, you need to use waitable lock that supports timeout.

Mutex or Event objects are such locks, but these are kernel objects, and don't have fast user mode path, like Critical Section has.

If you need Critical Section replacement, with fast user mode path, and with timeout, you have to create your own, or use a library facility -- there's no ready primitive in Windows API.

You can create it out of `SRWLOCK` and `CONDITION_VARIABLE` (wait on condition variable supports timeout), out of `WaitOnAddress` (it supports timeout), or out of Event and atomic variable (hardest of mentioned ways, but in Windows XP it was the only working).

Out of library solutions, if you are using C++, consider `timed_mutex` or `recursive_timed_mutex` from standard library.